# how to remove all zeros that are 7 characters long python

Tags: python, string, variables

I have made a string without spaces. so instead of spaces, I used 0000000. but there will be no alphabet letters. so for example, 000000020000000050000000190000000200000000 should equal "test". Sorry, I am very new to python and am not good. so if someone can help me out, that would be awesome.

Comment: This can't be done. If the significant data were always 2 characters (20, 05, 19, 20) then you could do it

Comment: Why has the "answer" from @Aggragoth been accepted when it clearly does not work?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You should be able to achieve the desired effect using regular expressions and `re.sub()`

If you want to extract the literal word "test" from that string as mentioned in the comments, you'll need to account for the fact that if you have 8 `0`'s, it will match the first 7 from left to right, so a number like `20` followed by 7 `0`'s would cause a few issues. We can get around this by matching the string in reverse (right to left) and then reversing the finished string to undo the initial reverse.

Here's the solution I came up with as my revised answer:

```py
import re

my_string = '000000020000000050000000190000000200000000'

# Substitute a space in place of 7 0's
# Reverse the string in the input, and then reverse the output
new_string = re.sub('0{7}', ' ', my_string[::-1])[::-1]
# >>> new_string
# ' 20 5 19 20 '
```

Then we can strip the leading and trailing whitespace from this answer and split it into an array

```py
my_array = new_string.strip().split()
# >>> my_array
# ['20', '5', '19', '20']
```

After that, you can process the array in whatever way you see fit to get the word "test" out of it.

My solution to that would probably be the following:

```py
import string

word = ''.join([string.ascii_lowercase[int(x) - 1] for x in my_array])
# >>> word
# 'test'
```

NOTE: This answer has been completely rewritten (v2).

Comment: There is no trim() function associated with Python strings

Comment: @Stuart whoops, I meant to put strip(), that's been edited now

Comment: why would the output be `['20', '5', '19', '20']` and not `['2, '05', '19', '2', '0']? Why would it leave the 0 from the '20' and not remove the *first* 7 0s in sequence?

Comment: @Aggragoth I do not understand how this can be the accepted answer. It does not produce either the OP's required output or even the output that you show in the answer. It's patently broken. In fact, the OP's requirement simply cannot be achieved

Comment: @Stuart You're right, major oversight on my part, however this CAN be achieved. I've just rewritten the answer with a working and tested solution this time. It should work for any valid input where the indexes of alphabetical characters are concerned.